# ReactJS Whitespace text nodes in <tbody>

Tags: reactjs

For some reason when assigning the variable 'row' as empty, throws the following error:

*Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of . Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code*

```
 render(){

    if(typeof(this.props.settings) ==="undefined"||Object.keys(this.props.settings).length==0)
    {
      //We haven't asked for Admins yet, so they don't exist.
       row ='';
    }
    else {
     ...
      row = nameArray.map((data,index) =>
    <tr key={index}><td>{data}</td>
      <td>{idArray[index]}</td>
      <td><div className="link_decoration" onClick={()=>this.props.removeRequest(idArray[index])}>Remove</div></td>
    </tr>
    );
  }
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
        <tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>SSO</th><th></th></tr>{row}</tbody></table>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

I can resolve the error by creating a placeholder instead of setting row='':

```
      nameArray.push("PlaceHolder");
      idArray.push("12345");
      row = nameArray.map((data,index) =>
    <tr key={index}><td>{data}</td>
      <td>{idArray[index]}</td>
      <td><div className="link_decoration" onClick={()=>this.props.removeRequest(idArray[index])}>Remove</div></td>
    </tr>
    );
    }
```

but there must be a better way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could solve it with

```
<tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>SSO</th><th></th></tr>{row.length > 0 ? row :null }</tbody></table>
```

More details about render and its return type could be found from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Also, it would be a good idea to indent your code.

Comment: Ahhh, or I can simply set row=null in my first IF statement instead of an empty string. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Does not use 'ternary operator':

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    {boolean ? <td>2</td> : ''}
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

use the '&&' operator:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    {boolean && <td>2</td>}
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```